# Working with recursion but not with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have written a code using recursion, but later realized that the depth is too high and does not work for higher level input values. It works completely fine without any issue.

```
def checkCount(first_window, index=0,reference_list=None):
    reference_list = []
    count = 0
    while index<=len(first_window)-2:
        if first_window[index] < first_window[index+1]:
            index += 1
            count += 1
        else: break
    if count != 0:
        reference_list.append(int((count*(count+1))/2))

    count = 0
    while index <= len(first_window)-2:
        if first_window[index] > first_window[index+1]:
            index += 1
            count += 1
        else: break
    if count != 0:
        reference_list.append(-int((count*(count+1))/2))

    if index > len(first_window)-2: return reference_list
    elif first_window[index] == first_window[index+1] and index<len(first_window)-2: index += 1

    reference_list = reference_list + checkCount(first_window, index, reference_list)
    return reference_list

import random
import time
start = time.clock()
input_array = list(map(int,"188930 194123 201345 154243 154243".split(" ")))
input_array = random.sample(range(1,100),10)

def main():

    N = len(input_array)
    K = 8
    if K == 1: return None

    print("Input array: ",input_array)
    print("First Window",input_array[:K])
    print("Real Output", checkCount(input_array[:K]))
if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

Now no matter how I try without recursion, it ends with an infinite loop. I have tried different ways but no progress.

One way I have tried is taking out the recursion statement and returning the referencelist + index:

```
def checkCount(..):
   ....
   ....
   return referencelist,index



while index <= K-2:
    print("While",index)
    reference_list, index = checkCount(new_input, index=0, reference_list=[])
    referencelist += reference_list
```

The application is similar to the [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/quora-haqathon/challenges/upvotes). But we have to deal with tons of data where recursion cannot help. Assume that the input array is greater than 100,000. I am really struck here, I do not understand what logic am I missing. Any help will be grateful.

Comment: You can simplify this please? Look at how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Your recursion seems upside-down.  You need a) **a terminal condition** and b) **the function calling itself with a reduced workload**  Try rethinking it with decrementing to zero.

Comment: @quadruplebucky I gave up on recursion because no matter what I do, it finally ends up with big recursion depth and python does not support more than 1000 depth call. Tried calling the recursion function with incremental steps but it makes the work more complicated for the other methods.

Comment: Don't use recursion unless its use makes more sense than iteration.

Comment: i would say that this recursion not working at all: you passing there same data. Moreover - you caused here *infinite recursion*  by calling checkCount inside checkCount without any condition. Based on this i would say that you not going deep with this, but just cycling doing nothing

Comment: `if index > len(first_window)-2: return reference_list` terminates the recursion call

Comment: And now the problem is not the recursion, changing that method to a iterator. This makes an infinite call which makes illogical.

Comment: @Reishin What are you talking about? The recursive function seems to be working fine (only that I have not understood what is really being done in the code)!!! The OP is interested in an iterative solution to get away from the disadvantages of recurrsion!!

Comment: Try putting the *terminal condition* at the very top of your loop and making sure the iterator moves every time the loop fires, not just when a pile of conditions are met.  Your counter variables are very difficult to figure.

Comment: @quadruplebucky say [1,2,3,5,5,2,1,2], the index values increase to 4(5>3>2>1) the next time it increases to 5(5 ==5) next time to 7(5<2<1). This is the core functionality, it is hard to use other counters because these will be random variables.

Comment: `print("Index is: ", index)`
    `print("len(first_window) is: ", len(first_window))` above your recursive call.  Counters are **not** working.  Your code is broken when your test array has two identical values.  **simplify**.

Comment: Yes, it repeats in the same if I try to print the index. `reference_list, index = checkCount(new_input, index)` trying this several times increases the index though(hard coding it iteratively)., it is problem only if I use while loop.

Comment: @officialaimm if you dont understand, how you can tell that it working? lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *first_window* variable is only read, and the *index* variable is only incremented. There is no need for recursion, a simple loop can work.

```
def check_count(first_window):
    reference_list = []
    index = 0
    while index < len(first_window) - 2:
        count = 0
        while index <= len(first_window) - 2:
            if first_window[index] < first_window[index + 1]:
                index += 1
                count += 1
            else:
                break
        if count != 0:
            reference_list.append(int((count * (count + 1)) / 2))

        count = 0
        while index <= len(first_window) - 2:
            if first_window[index] > first_window[index + 1]:
                index += 1
                count += 1
            else:
                break
        if count != 0:
            reference_list.append(-int((count * (count + 1)) / 2))

        if index < len(first_window) - 2 and first_window[index] == first_window[index + 1]:
            index += 1

    return reference_list
```

Of course, this algorithm can be optimised, for instance, we can avoid repetitions like: `len(first_window) - 2`.